# Failed to pass uniform in Metal shader modifier

Tags: shaders, ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to write a simple shader able to pass the color to be used for drawing in the fragment shader, through a uniform. I load the shader modifier and pass the uniform:

```
let fragmentShaderPath = bundle.pathForResource("Cube", ofType: "fragment")!
let fragmentShader = try String(contentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPath)

let shaderModifiers : [String:String] = [
    SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment : fragmentShader
]

cube.geometry?.shaderModifiers = shaderModifiers

SCNTransaction.begin()
cube.geometry?.setValue(NSValue(SCNVector4: SCNVector4Make(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)), forKey: "myColor")
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

And this is my fragment shader modifier code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

float4 myColor;

_output.color = myColor;
```

But nothing happens: the object is drawn as black. If I try declaring *myColor* as a uniform, I get an error:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you need to include "#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;" in the modifier ? Is it not already included in the main shader the modifier snippet is going to fit in?